# Display image data in android with javafx

Tags: java, android, javafx, gluon, javafxports

I am using JavaFX code based to develop an Android application using openSource JavaFxPorts.I have a working snippet for displaying the image data from the sockets in JavaFX.

```
                        Mat frame = new Mat();
                        buffer = packet.getData();
                        frame = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(buffer), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
                        Image imageToShow = Utils.mat2Image(frame);
                        Utils.onFXThread(mainGui.maincontroller.getImageView().imageProperty(), imageToShow);
                        Utils.onFXThread( GUIMotionComposer.m_cFrameView.imageProperty(), imageToShow);
```

How to use this existing code or what changes are necessary to make above code compatible with Android ?

build.gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.16'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: "me.tatarka.retrolambda"
apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'


retrolambda {
  javaVersion JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
  defaultMethods false
  incremental true
}

mainClassName = 'org.fxgui.mainGui'

repositories {
    jcenter()

}

dependencies {
    //compile files('libs/MCLibrary_state.jar','libs/opencv-340.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


    retrolambdaConfig 'net.orfjackal.retrolambda:retrolambda:+'
}

sourceSets.main {
    java {
        srcDir 'src/main/java/org/fxgui'
    }
    resources {
        srcDirs = ['src/main/resources/images', 'src/main/resources']
        include "**/*.fxml"
    }

}



jfxmobile {
    javafxportsVersion = '8.60.9'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = '23'
        buildToolsVersion = '23.0.3'
        androidSdk = 'C:\\Users\\sairam\\androidsdk'

         packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    exclude 'META-INF/jdom-info.xml'
    exclude 'LICENSE'
    exclude 'NOTICE'
    exclude '**'
    exclude 'META-INF/services/org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory'
    exclude 'META-INF/**'
    exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    }

    }
```

Utils.java

```
package org.fxgui;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;



//import android.graphics.Bitmap;

//import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;


/**
 * Provide general purpose methods for handling OpenCV-JavaFX data conversion.
 * Moreover, expose some "low level" methods for matching few JavaFX behavior.
 *
 * @author <a href="mailto:luigi.derussis@polito.it">Luigi De Russis</a>
 * @author <a href="http://max-z.de">Maximilian Zuleger</a>
 * @version 1.0 (2016-09-17)
 * @since 1.0
 * 
 */
public final class Utils
{
    /**
     * Convert a Mat object (OpenCV) in the corresponding Image for JavaFX
     *
     * @param frame
     *            the {@link Mat} representing the current frame
     * @return the {@link Image} to show
     */
    public static Image mat2Image(Mat frame)
    {
        try
        {
            return SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(matToBufferedImage(frame), null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Cannot convert the Mat obejct: " + e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generic method for putting element running on a non-JavaFX thread on the
     * JavaFX thread, to properly update the UI
     * 
     * @param property
     *            a {@link ObjectProperty}
     * @param value
     *            the value to set for the given {@link ObjectProperty}
     */
    public static <T> void onFXThread(final ObjectProperty<T> property, final T value)
    {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            property.set(value);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Support for the {@link mat2image()} method
     * 
     * @param original
     *            the {@link Mat} object in BGR or grayscale
     * @return the corresponding {@link BufferedImage}
     */
    private static BufferedImage matToBufferedImage(Mat original)
    {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        int width = original.width(), height = original.height(), channels = original.channels();
        byte[] sourcePixels = new byte[width * height * channels];
        original.get(0, 0, sourcePixels);

        if (original.channels() > 1)
        {
            image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        }
        else
        {
            image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        }
        final byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        System.arraycopy(sourcePixels, 0, targetPixels, 0, sourcePixels.length);

        return image;
    }






}
```

Thank You

Comment: If you have a gradle project, created by the Gluon plugin for your IDE, that project will run on desktop and Android, providing the dependencies can be ported to Android. Edit your question and post more details about those dependencies, and your build.gradle file.

Comment: @JoséPereda yes my project is created using Gluon plugin in Eclipse IDE, with my project i'm able to generate an APK also but in my application, I have an requirement to convert mat data (opencv) to buffered image. Debugging APK I found that buffered image class is not supported in android, looking for alternative approach to use Utils.java without buffered image for android.

Comment: Yes, Swing is not supported on mobile. But there are pure JavaFX alternatives to do the same, using `PixelWriter`, based on the `targetPixels` from OpenCV.

Comment: @JoséPereda Great :) Thanks for your Input using `WritableImage` and `PixelWriter`I have achieved my desired behaviour for android :)